# @Asynchronous method in Tomee generates memory leak log error

Tags: jakarta-ee, asynchronous, ejb, apache-tomee

I have a `@Asynchronous` method in a singleton class which gets called from a EJB to do some cleanup in the system.

```
@Singleton
public class AuthTokenCleanup {

    @Inject
    AuthTokenService tokenService;

    @Asynchronous
    @Lock(LockType.READ)
    @TransactionAttribute(NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public void scheduleCleanupAuthTokens() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            tokenService.cleanup();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

The snippet of code that is calling the singleton. It is inside a `@Stateless` EJB

```
public boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {

      boolean authenticated = false;

      try{  
        Login login = loginLookup.findByUsername(username);
        authenticated = login.equalPassword(password);
      } finally {
        tokenCleanup.scheduleCleanupAuthTokens(); //token cleanup happens here
      }

      return authenticated;
}
```

When undeploying the application it takes about 20-30 seconds.
I see the following error in the catalina log file

```
SEVERE: The web application [/MyApp] 
appears to have started a thread named [@Asynchronous MyApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT - 3] 
but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

I'm running the application on Apache-tomee-1.7.1-jaxrs.
A snippet of my pom.xml config

```
    <properties>
        <tomee.version>1.7.1</tomee.version>
        <openejb.javaee.api>6.0-6</openejb.javaee.api>        
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
          <compilerArguments>
               <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
          </compilerArguments>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

When I remove the `@Asynchronous` call the undeploy takes 1-3 seconds and no error in log file.

Is the behavior and error expected in TomEE when using a `@Asynchronous` method call if not what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found that the `Thread.sleep(5000);` is causing the un-deploy time and error in the log file. Is there a way to have a sleep or timeout on the async call that executes after some time but is also in line with thread compliance in the EE contrainer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EJB spec requires that EJB components do not [directly access thread primitives](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/restrictions-142267.html) (including `Thread.sleep()`).  This is because the container needs to handle thread management, and won't be able to do this efficiently if the application is doing this.

If the clean-up task needs to be done regularly in a singleton, have you considered using a [scheduled job](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html), using the `@Schedule` annotation?  This will fit better with the EJB model, and also means that you're not starting a new asynchronous request for every call processed, so it's likely to scale much better too.